# Symfony 4, проблема с миграциями

Tags: mysql, symfony

Столкнулся с проблемой при выполнении миграций в Symfony 4, нужно добавить новое поле в таблицу

При попытке выполнить миграции получаю следующее:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too
> large. The maximum row size for the used table    type, not counting
> BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You
> have to change some colu   mns to TEXT or BLOBs

При том ошибка выходит вне зависимости от выбираемого типа поля - будь то string или text.

Из ошибки делаю вывод, что уткнулся в какие-то ограничения на размер строк MySQL (MySQL 8.0), но вот куда копать, что бы это исправить - не понимаю.

Так вот, куда копать, что бы исправить это дело?

Comment: Кода нет, но сообщение об ошибке явно говорит, что для больших размеров данных вам нужно изменить тип поля на TEXT или BLOB

Comment: Без кода сложно что то сказать, кроме того что проблема не касается symfony, очевидно.